# Eclipse Java Having some hard time opening Project in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

Some hours ago this worked fine but for some reason, the look of my Eclipse IDE under Java EE mode changed and now when I go to import a project into the work-space, I am unable to see it displayed in Project explorer, and so unable to run it. Any hints on how this is done?

[image]

Above is an image of the project view even after an import in Java EE mode. No error messages showed up

Comment: Can you upload any picture? Anything??

Comment: check to make sure you are in the Java perspective

Comment: @mattb It should stil display every project, even Python projects for example...

Comment: I have edited to include an image

Comment: This is really crazy I must admit. Make sure you are importing your project right way: File > Import > General > Existing Project into Workspace. Browse in "Select root directory" field. Otherwise go [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) to report a bug.

Comment: I think the problem is specific to some of my project files and not all. I was able to import an old project but still not able to import the current project I have been working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else, open the **Navigator View** and make sure the project's actually there.

From the **Project Explorer** view's local menu, "Select Working Set" and make sure "No Working Sets" is what you choose.  Also from the local menu, select "Customize View" and verify that you're not Filtering out anything you might want, and that you've enabled showing all the types of Content you want.